# Understand AppHangB1 event and Hang Type

Tags: c++

I have a game that often hangs. When the hang happens it switches back to the Windows Desktop, and cannot be brought back to front ever again. Only thing left to do is close it via Task Manager (or taskkill, etc)

From the Event Viewer I can dig the following application hand event description:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: AppHangB1
Application Name:   [It does not matter at this point]
Application Version:    0.9.14.0
Application Timestamp:  56d56d8f
Hang Signature: 45f9
Hang Type:  2048
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Hang Signature 1:    45f925d9ade4d1a06157e0757d709b29
Additional Hang Signature 2:    a6bb
Additional Hang Signature 3:    a6bb9b65a991c52828e98b8adc752872
Additional Hang Signature 4:    45f9
Additional Hang Signature 5:    45f925d9ade4d1a06157e0757d709b29
Additional Hang Signature 6:    a6bb
Additional Hang Signature 7:    a6bb9b65a991c52828e98b8adc752872
```

**Question:** Does anyone know what the ***hang type*** or ***hang signature*** is? After doing some googling I couldn't find any results explaining different hang types.

Note: please don't tell me to contact the game developers, I've done so, and they aren't really helpful. I would like to figure out if this hang is related to my hardware or a bug in their code.

Yes, I know it is their code running that hangs, but is it due to my hardware misbehaving, a wrong driver or really just a bug in the game code.

Comment: They appear to be flags of some sort, or at least they are always seem to have one bit set. I get 2097152 which is 2\*\*30. It looks like they map to the "problem text" field at the top, which is "Stopped responding and was closed" in my case

Comment: In my case the Hang Type is 33554432 which is 2^25. So it **does** appear to be a flag.